Why can't I change the value of a mock object property that hasn't been set up?
I'm new to unit testing, and I'm writing unit tests for .NET C# applications. To create mocks, I use the MOQ NuGet package in my test project. I have an interface with two properties:
public interface IUserInput
{
    public int FirstInput { get; set; }
    public int SecondInput { get; set; }
}

I have a class that works with this interface:
public class CalculatorCore : ICalculatorBase
{
    private readonly IUserInput _input;

    public CalculatorCore(IUserInput input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }

    public int AddByUserInput()
    {
        _input.SecondInput += 2;
        return _input.FirstInput + _input.SecondInput;
    }
}

For this class, I've written a test class and a test method:
[TestClass]
public class CalculatorCoreTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AddByUserInput()
    {
        Mock<IUserInput> userInputMock = new Mock<IUserInput>();
        userInputMock.SetupProperty(f => f.FirstInput, 1);
        userInputMock.SetupProperty(f => f.SecondInput, 1);

        var calculatorCore = new CalculatorCore(userInputMock.Object);

        var actual = calculatorCore.AddByUserInput();
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, 4);
    }
}

This test passes and I do not have any problem. 
However, when I remove the line
  userInputMock.SetupProperty(f => f.SecondInput, 1);

and change the assert part of the code to
Assert.AreEqual(actual, 3);

the test fails, and my result is 1. This happens because when I add 2 to my mock object property, it still equals 0;
Why can't I change the value of a mock object property that hasn't been set up?

Without setup the property can't be set. To make it visual it'll act like the following property:
int SecondInput { set {} get => default; }

So it'll always return a 0. If you want to have all mocked properties act like real properties you can also call SetupAllProperties() on your mock to quickly setup the behavior you're looking for.

Thank you for your response. Your answer provided clarity on my issue and how to resolve it.

This question, as well as the answer by NotFound suggests that the API being tested might be improved.
Instead of using Moq to supply an instance of IUserInput, why don't you create a proper class?
public sealed class UserInput : IUserInput
{
    public int FirstInput { get; set; }
    public int SecondInput { get; set; }
}

This makes the test simpler and more robust:
[Fact]
public void AddByUserInput()
{
    var userInput = new UserInput { FirstInput = 1, SecondInput = 1 };
    var calculatorCore = new CalculatorCore(userInput);

    var actual = calculatorCore.AddByUserInput();

    Assert.Equal(4, actual);
}

In fact, once you've done that, then why do you need the interface?
What purpose is an interface with two properties? An interface is a way to introduce polymorphism in C# code, but how many valid ways are there to implement a read/write property? Do you really need to vary that behaviour?
As the answer by NotFound suggests, there are several wrong ways you can implement an interface like IUserInput, but in the majority of cases, only one useful way.
Thus, unless you have some compelling reason to keep the interface, change CalculatorCore to take a concrete class as input:
public class CalculatorCore : ICalculatorBase
{
    private readonly UserInput _input;

    public CalculatorCore(UserInput input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }

    public int AddByUserInput()
    {
        _input.SecondInput += 2;
        return _input.FirstInput + _input.SecondInput;
    }
}

or, perhaps, address the Feature Envy by applying the Move Method refactoring:
public sealed class UserInput
{
    public int FirstInput { get; set; }
    public int SecondInput { get; set; }

    public int AddByUserInput()
    {
        SecondInput += 2;
        return FirstInput + SecondInput;
    }
}

This further simplifies the test:
[Fact]
public void AddOnUserInput()
{
    var userInput = new UserInput { FirstInput = 1, SecondInput = 1 };
    var actual = userInput.AddByUserInput();
    Assert.Equal(4, actual);
}

This is a good example of how writing tests shines a useful light on the design of the System Under Test.

Thank you for your response. I completely agree with your insights. Additionally, I appreciate your taking the time to respond to me. I simply wanted to provide an example to illustrate the issue encountered while studying Unit Testing. When writing real code, I will adhere to all necessary principles.
